# Kubernetes - Unable to access apache Pod from proxy

Tags: apache, docker, kubernetes

I have PHP app+Apache on a Kubernetes POD. The PHP app, access Elasticsearch API on port 9200, and show a simple website, to the users, on port 5000.

I run proxy, using `kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --port=8001 --accept-hosts='.*'`.

When I enter to `"http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/website/proxy/"`, I see the following error:

```
Error: 'dial tcp 172.17.0.6:5000: connect: connection refused'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.17.0.6:5000/'
```

*172.17.0.6 is the POD ip address.

This is the website POD yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: website
  labels:
    app: website
spec:
  containers:
  - name: website
    image: website_k8s:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5000
    - containerPort: 80
```

This is the dockerfile of website_k8s:latest:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
RUN echo "ServerName 0.0.0.0" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY ./index.php /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 5000
```

---

I also tried to run service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: website-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: serving
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    name: readfromelasticsearch
  selector:
    app: website
```

And when I enter to `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/website-service/proxy/`, I see:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"website-service\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

Even though, when I run `$kubectl get endpoints website-service`, I see:

```
NAME              ENDPOINTS                       AGE
website-service   172.17.0.6:80,172.17.0.6:9200   59m
```

I see the service's POD endpoint.

How could I access my website via proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Apache is listening on port 80, not 5000.

If you remove `containerPort: 5000` then you can access the website via `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/website/proxy/`.

Secondly, the endpoints you see for the service are internal to the cluster.
So, you can access the service through those IP endpoints from within a pod: `kubectl exec website -- curl 172.17.0.6/`.
If you want to expose your service externally, the service should be of type `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`.

Finally, the problem you have when querying the service through the proxy is that, when you give a name to a port, you have to include it in the proxy call: `curl localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/website-service:serving/proxy/`.